# Scala Play 2.6: How to design an efficient health check?

Tags: scala, playframework, health-monitoring

As you know having a health check is important feature to have when you put your application in production.

In one hand I don't want to put everything under the sun into my health check and in other hand I don't want to show just a string for a health check.

So my question here is, how to design an efficient health check for an application in production?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Scala and Play in particular? Or are you just looking for general advice that could apply to any app, built with any language, using any framework?

Comment: @FriedBrice It is regarding play app/scala and JVM.

Comment: https://github.com/hmrc/play-health?

Comment: @FriedBrice doesnt do anything really and it uses 2.2.3.  I mean look at its tests: https://github.com/hmrc/play-health/blob/master/test/uk/gov/hmrc/play/health/AdminSpec.scala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What sort of health checks do you want to export? To get started, I would recommend doing the following:

1. Use codahale metrics with which you can spit out the JVM metrics
2. If your application has downstream systems, you can expose the connection details of those downstream systems. This might help you to do some infrastructure level checks with which you can eventually trigger some alerts if one of your downstream goes offline
3. You can also expose the DB connection pool connection status
4. For metrics related to HTTP requests, you could look at Twitter's ostrich framework!

You can expose all these checks as an API endpoint which can then be called at regular intervals by some infrastructure monitoring tools!

Comment: Isnt Ostrich outdated? Are you using it?

Comment: That was just a suggestion from my past experience. If there is something better that that, yes we could use it!